# Refresh QTableWidget with new values

Tags: qt, qtgui

I have two forms - `form1`, `form2`.
`form1` has got a `QTableWidget` which reads and shows `xml` entries in folder.

`form2` is a dialog form, collect user data and save as `xml`.

I need to implement the following:
Pressing `button1` in `form2` save (this is working) and close the window and immediately refresh `QTabletWidget` in `form1` with new values.

Could you show me a way to implement this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easy workaround without `signal & slot`: 
close form 1(btw , it is QMainwindow) when form 2 is created. Then when I press button form 2 will be closed and a new form 1 will be created. Like this:

```
this->close(); ---->form 2
MainWindow *back = new MainWindow(this);
back->show();
```